# Bugzilla installation issue in Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, bugzilla, solaris-10

I encountered the following error when installing Bugzilla in Solaris 10.

Can anyone advise on how to resolve the issues? I am installing on a Solaris 10 x86 machine.

```
# /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Digest::SHA
/usr/ucb/cc: language optional software package not installed
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target 'SHA.o'

# /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime
Error: no compiler detected to compile 'lib/DateTime.c'. Aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
export CC
CC=gcc
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Digest::SHA
```